# Overlap two absolute divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `container` with two absolute positioned `divs` in it.

The first div contains **text + buttons**.
The second div contains a .png with **cars** represented on it

My website is responsive, so the text resizes when the window becomes smaller, and this got me into trouble. At certain width, the text goes into two lines, instead of one and this creates some more space between my **absolute** positioned divs, messing the layout a little (the cars aren't fully on the road).

1) http://prntscr.com/9e0bq4 (the window is wide enough for the text to stay in one line)
2) http://prntscr.com/9e0c2y (the window is less wide and the text goes into two lines)

I **can't change** the position to relative or fixed, because it will break my animations and I **can't** make the font smaller to fit in one line at any resolution, because the smaller the width gets, the harder it becomes to read.

How do I make `#cars` "more absolute" and ignore that `#header` is also absolute?

***Here's my code:***
HTML

```
<section id="home" >    // container    
    <div id="home1inner">   // a container inside it with a bigger height, so it allow scrolling
        <div id="header">
            *way too much to code to insert it all here*
        </div>

        <img id="cars" src="images/cars.png" />
    </div>      
</section>
```

CSS

```
   #home {

    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% + 25px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-image: url('images/movie_6.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 690px;
    margin-top: 40px;       
    }

    #home1inner {
        height: 1490px;
    }

    #header{
    width: 75%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -37.5%;
    }

    #cars {
    position: absolute;
    height: 690px;
    bottom: -500px;
    margin-left: -300px;
    }
```

**UPDATE** :
Here's http://jsfiddle.net/denea/2oexep8u/8/embedded/result/ (scroll and resize the window, cars stay at the same height), with the same code, working fine when you resize the window. Though the `cars` are moving down when I resize the window on my local files. Is there a difference between the code here and in the jsfiddle that I didn't spot?

Comment: please share live link where we can see the issue in action and then can help. Thanx

Comment: img {max-width:100%;} provided, remove other values from #car except, pos:abs

Comment: Like Leo said, a live link would be the best way for anyone to figure out what's going on - from what I can make out the header element has a margin on each side preventing the text from having access to the entire width of the window.

Comment: A few moments and I'll paste a jsfiddle, because I started creating one and it's working perfectly fine there, thought it's exactly the same code ...

Comment: Updated, the same code works fine on jsfiddle, though locally, I get the thing from the two screenshots I posted. It's the same code copied from my index.html everywhere

Answer (score 1):

fine the window width ( if cannont try this in consol : window.innerWidth )

now use the media query : 
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) { your #car and #header style here }

change the 992 width to your screen with which is put u in trouble :)

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to do this, but there are way too many widths at which I have to re-style `#cars`, because sometimes the text goes even into 3 lines, so there are about 15 widths that need to be re-styled.